# Stata menbreg - cluster standard errors at lower level

Tags: stata

I am using Stata's `menbreg` command to estimate a multilevel mixed-effect negative binomial regression on cross-sectional count data. The outcome is measured at the firm level, nested in counties, nested in states.  I would like to cluster the standard errors at the county level, but Stata seems to only allow me to cluster at the highest level (states).

When I try to use `vce(cluster county`) to cluster the SEs at the county level, Stata gives me the following warning:
highest-level groups are not nested within county

Here is my basic code:

```
menbreg dv iv, exposure(size) vce(cluster county) || state:
```

I've noticed that when using `menbreg`, the `vce(robust)` option also seems to estimate SEs clustered at the state level.

Comment: I don't know anything about this command, but you don't explain much about your data. At a guess (this is an international site) you have data for the United States, and I would first make sure that you are not being bitten because there are counties with the same name in different states.

Comment: Thanks, Nick - yes, it is data for the US.  That's a good guess, but I am using fips codes for the counties, so each county has a unique number.

Comment: It is tough to answer without a data example, but you issue sounds similar to this:  (https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1412121-mixed-cluster-error)